# What is user_data in CodeIgniter session used to?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

When i in CodeIgniter run `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());` it prints

```
array (size=5)
  'session_id' => string '3403084ad9f5e2582a8d9269ceb68fb7' (length=32)
  'ip_address' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'user_agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)' (length=64)
  'last_activity' => int 1365456079
  'user_data' => string '' (length=0)
```

Since these are automatically filled in values by CI, I'm wondering if I could/should overwrite the user_data index, with e.g 'user_data' => $username.

If CI keep update this index, this will not work. Than i must store my session-data with my own indexes. Anybody with experience on CI that knows what this fixed index in the session array is used for. There is no documentation for it.

Comment: Most people will never need to modify this column directly. You should add or remove session data using the [methods available to you](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Answer (score 3):

the `user_data` field is used for all your extra session params

once you want to put a session value you use to do:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('x','y');
```

the `userdata('x')` is then stored in the `user_data` array key of the session with the `y` value

so your `user_data` key in session now will look like (or somenthing similar :D ):

```
'user_data' => ['x'=>'y']
```

so definitely ,yes , you WILL overwrite the value of user_data, just setting some session value you need/want

More About the user_data field from the doc seems to be the db field that CI uses to store your session params:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

in the system7libraries/session.php there is no big trace of `user_data` just for these lines:

```
// Run the update query
        $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
        $this->CI->db->update($this->sess_table_name, array('last_activity' => $this->userdata['last_activity'], 'user_data' => $custom_userdata));
```

which seems are updating a db field called `user_data` which (seems) to be related to the session db

Comment: Not with me. I get
  'session_id' => string 'cc8df0989ae26188260d184f6e40ea7e' (length=32)
  'ip_address' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'user_agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31' (length=101)
  'last_activity' => int 1365457537
  'user_data' => string '' (length=0)
  'x' => string 'y' (length=1)

Comment: @VidarVestnes probably it's a CI needing to have it as it is, i need to test it out on my own sec i tell you ;)

Comment: @VidarVestnes so strange actually i have no user_data index, did you tryed destroying session and recreating session? it is not your own session param right? :D

Comment: Nope, as you can see in the Session.php under the systems folder. Somewhere close to line 321, it uses an array with an index = user_data, and saves it to both db and cookie... But i do understand what you mean :-) CI, is always storing/creating this index

Comment: @VidarVestnes this seems to be normal, but the fact it sets that as string anywy leave me a dubt, the doc shows user_data as a db field http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html (in which is stored YOUR session) you leave me a dubt anyway uhm